# Estimate average brightness of a grayscale picture with opencv

Tags: opencv

I have a grayscale picture, and I would to transform it to black and white only. But for that, I need to calculate the right threshold, and I would like that threshold to be equal to the average brightness of the picture.

So, I was wondering how I could calculate that threshold with OpenCV. Is there a method existing in the framework to do that easily ?

I wanted to add every value of brightness (between 0 and 255) for every pixel, then divide the sum by the number of pixel itself, but the method I found to access those datas is really slow (.at(i,j)[k] for a rgb picture). But my picture is in grayscale, and I would like it to be quite fast, so it can be run on an iPhone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To calculate these statistics, use `cv::sum()`, or even better, `cv::mean()`.

However, OpenCV already has a thresholding function that does everything you want to do for you:
[cv::adaptiveThreshold()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#void%20adaptiveThreshold%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20double%20maxValue,%20int%20adaptiveMethod,%20int%20thresholdType,%20int%20blockSize,%20double%20C%29)

Also you should check out Otsu's method, see `cv::threshold()` with `THRESH_OTSU` option.

Comment: Finally, my method wont work, because of the bad quelity of the picture, so even if "sum" and "mean" do what I wanted, I'll use the cv::adaptiveThreshold(), which is way better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Monte Carlo algorithm, sampling random points instead of all image points until you have covered 1% of the image. The result should be very similar to the actual value.