# Get brightness and contrast of an image in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, brightness

I am trying to do some image processing in python3.7 using openCV 4+. I need to add a filter where it checks for the brightness of the input image/frame(if video) and then decides whether to change brightness or not. Can some one help me how do I get the brightness of the current image?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is no "brightness" absolute value stored in images. Whereas, you can compute the mean of the image luminance, and consider it to be the `0` brightness to enable the user to add/remove brightness, or calculate the difference between this mean and the wanted one, to adjust it.

You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501865/estimate-average-brightness-of-a-grayscale-picture-with-opencv).

Comment: okk thanks a lot will try this and let you know if it is giving the desired result!

Comment: @AayushLakkad, do you get the output as you expected?